# How to integrate passport.js POST server-side login routes with react client-side navigation and routing?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, passport.js, react-redux, react-routing

I'd like to implement a redux action that triggers the passport.js authentication.

Passport's implementation is server-side and is POST route at /login on the express server.

I am using react starter kit with isomorphic rendering.

https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/recipes/how-to-implement-routing.md

React starter kit uses client-side and isomorphic routing, but the passport.js authentication routes are not exposed to the react-starter-kit routing.

How do I:

1. trigger the server side POST /login route from a redux action client-side?
2. Is there a way for me to keep the client-side routing integrated with the passport.js server side login routes so that it renders isomorhpically?  It seems odd to have a set of server-side routes for login that the client has no knowledge of.

I currently have a client-side route for /login that just has a big button that says Login which triggers a form post.  Is it a hack to keep that page but just auto-trigger the form post on render?

Comment: by any chance did you find an anwer to this? I'm trying to implement authentication while using server side rendering and redux

Comment: I had to do a hack where I trigger a hard navigation link from the client triggering a server side load, whenever I need to go to /login or /logout - bypassing the client-side routing all together

Comment: thanks I decided to use JWT and handle it on client from there